# Netezza Timesptamp failing

Tags: netezza

I'm trying to query the database as flows:

```
select count(distinct(TE_ID)) from TE where LAST_UPDATE_TIME >= '2013-01-08-00:00:00.000000' and LAST_UPDATE_TIME < '2013-01-09-00:00:00.000000'
```

However the error I receive is:

```
 11:25:09  [SELECT - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  [Error Code: 1100, SQL State: HY000]  ERROR:  Bad timestamp external representation '2013-01-08-00:00:00.000000'
```

... 1 statement(s) executed, 0 row(s) affected, exec/fetch time: 0.000/0.000 sec  [0 successful, 0 warnings, 1 errors]

Answer (score 1):

The timestamp you are giving has an extra dash.

Yours: `select cast('2013-01-08-00:00:00.000000' as timestamp)`

Should be: `select cast('2013-01-08 00:00:00.000000' as timestamp)`

To control it might be a good idea to explicitly cast like the example below:

`to_timestamp('2013-01-08 00:00:00.000000','YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS.US')`

- HH = Hour
- MI = Minute
- SS = Second
- US = Microseconds

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  select count(distinct(TE_ID)) from TE where LAST_UPDATE_TIME >= '2013-01-08 00:00:00.000000' and LAST_UPDATE_TIME < '2013-01-09 00:00:00.000000'
```